# Facing problem while publishing the component - Invalid parameter

Tags: 5.3, dynamic-publishing

I have simple general component having one RTF field and one component link field for showing banner image.

Other component are working fine but one of them is showing error. I thought due to long length of file name creating problem so I made short name for file. But problem is still there.

Below is screenshot:

[image]

Below is the error from Template builder:

```
Invalid parameter: variantId (how-to-print-greener-in-2014_16001067_801691319_1_0_14099332_100-64x64.png).
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.Binary.AssertValidVariantId(String variantId)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.Binary..ctor(Component multimediaComponent, Publication location, String variantId, RenderInstruction renderInstruction)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderedItem.AddBinary(Component multimediaComponent, String variantId)
   at MyCompany.BuildingBlocks.AddInlineBinaries.Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className)
   at Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine __engine, Package __package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggingEngine.Run()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebugSession.Run()
```

Tridion Version : 5.3

Thanks,

Comment: Look for the line that calls AddBinary within this method: MyCompany.BuildingBlocks.AddInlineBinaries.Transform(Engine engine, Package package)

Comment: Its published now after making the name more shorter "how-to-print-greener.png"

Answer (score 1):

This could be custom TBB code, probably a TBB that publishes binaries. Somewhere where a engine.AddBinary() call is made with a variant id param.

Run this template with Template Builder against the same component and see if it breaks with a stacktrace and a line number.  You can also look at the publisher logs. It will give you more info on where it is faulting.

Comment: Even without a line number, a search for calls to `AddBinary` in ` at `MyCompany.BuildingBlocks.AddInlineBinaries.Transform` would probably be a decent place to start.

Comment: Its published now after making the name more shorter "how-to-print-greener.png"